# Can scope properties be passed by reference in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, parameter-passing

Would the below code work as intended in an AngularJS controller?

```
 updateProperty($scope.property1);

 var updateProperty=function(property){
    property+=1;
    /* Will the above line change $scope.property1? */
 }
```

If the above syntax does not work, is there another way to create a generic function that can be used to update any scope property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this runs inside a controller where $scope is injected, this is what you could do:

```
updateScopeProperty("property1");

function updateScopeProperty(propertyName) {
    $scope[propertyName] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Passing `$scope` is not necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

Primary types cannot be passed by reference. Try with passing object:

```
$scope.property1 = {
  value: 1
};
updateProperty($scope.property1);

var updateProperty=function(property){
  property.value += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why do we need the `$scope.apply();` statement here? I thought it was only needed if we were updating the scope on a background thread?

Comment: @Price Indeed - maybe I shouldn't mention about it here. ;-)